# "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException" with Guice Singleton in parent class

Tags: java, singleton, guice, dropwizard

I would need some clarification on Guice injection, since I spent days trying to understand how it works in my particular context without positive results.

I have a Java application built on Dropwizard environment (not sure if relevant).

The entry point is the classic main where the guice injector is created:

```
injector = Guice.createInjector(new MyAppModule(configuration, environment));
```

MyAppModule is where I bind the interface class to my implementation:

```
bind(EventService.class).to(MyEventServiceImpl.class).asEagerSingleton();
```

EventService has to be a managed singleton and it needs Guice in case some other implementation comes up, at the moment I only have one.

Now, the injection I need should happen in a base class BaseException, where I have this code:

```
public class BaseException extends RuntimeException {

    private final int statusCode;
    private final int errorCode;
    private final String errorDetails;

    @Inject
    private EventService eventService;

    public BaseException(int statusCode, int errorCode, String errorDetails) {
            this(statusCode, errorCode, null, errorDetails);
    }

    @Inject
    public BaseException(int statusCode, int errorCode, String errorMessage, String errorDetails) {
        super(errorMessage);
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
        this.errorDetails = errorDetails;
        // this.eventService = eventService // this would require parameter passing here and on all children classes?

        notifyEventService();
    }

    public void notifyEventService()
    {
        eventService.send(MyEnum.TYPE, super.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I then have a child class MyCustomException:

```
public class MyCustomException extends BaseException {

    public MyCustomException(int statusCode, int errorCode, String errorMessage, String errorDetails) {
        super(statusCode, errorCode, errorMessage, errorDetails);
    }
}
```

The idea is that at every custom exception the event service notification fires.
The problem is that the EventService object doesn't really get injected and I don't know if it's a design problem or just a misunderstanding of Guice from my part.

When I try to throw a MyCustomException, I get a `"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException"` instead. The null value being eventService in the notifyEventService() method.
I tried several @Inject combinations but I am unable to access my EventService object.

I am very new to Guice, but I have been reading a lot and looking at examples, I thought the main idea was that it could magically obtain the singleton instance created in the injector no matter which class I try to access it from.
Many solutions here involve using `injector.getInstance(EventService.class)` but I would need a reference to it anyway and it looks dirty.
I'm open to any suggestion at this point.

Comment: There's no magic. The Di system is what _wires_ everything together. In order for this wiring to happen, the system actually needs to know about all the participants. On top of that, if you are going to instantiate an object yourself, you're saying that you don't want the Di system to have anything to do with the creation. With that said, in order for what you are trying to do to work, you would also need to bind the exception class to Guice, and not just that, but let Guice create the exception instance. You would need to retrieve the exception instance from the injector before you throw it.

Comment: Where do you bind `MyCustomException`? Show us that module. If you don't bind it, but instantiate it by yourself (=call `new`), how would Guice know that you want it to be injected?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha @OlivierGrégoire thanks both, you're right I am indeed throwing MyCustomException by calling ```new```, because I need to be able to call it from any class, not only where my injector is accessible (main). Is it good practice to even let Guice control my exceptions? That would mean a lot of refactoring for all exceptions in the project. I would need an elegant way to only inject the EventService singleton object if possible at all.

Comment: I think having the Exception class tied to the service is very limiting and a poor design. You could have a service that injects the EventService and handles the creation of, and maybe also throwing of exceptions. This way there is a helper in between to connect the service and the exceptions. The exceptions should not know anything about any services.